# Dynamic nav bar with php works properly but when trying to input sub-menu with foreach getting error

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My nav bar is working properly if i have just menu items. When i add sub-menu items i get error and display only the first item.

I think that probably i have my php tags in wrong position. Tryied to change that but still get error.

```
 Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in
```

What am i doning wrong?

this is my code

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <?php 
            foreach ($navItems as $item) { ?>
                <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="<?php echo $item['slug']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $item['title']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>

                 <?php 
                        if(isset($item['dropdown'])){ ?>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                             <?php foreach ($item as $subitem){ ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <ul class="col-sm-3">
               // this line gives me error                                      
              <li><a href="<?php echo $subitem['slug'];?>"> <?php echo $subitem['title'];?></a>                          
                                            </ul>
                            <?php       }

                        } ?>

                <?php } ?>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
```

And my nav.php with arrays

```
        //Nav Items
        $navItems = array(
            array(
                'slug'      => "navItem.php",
                'title'     => " navItem",
                'dropdown'  => array(
                                    array(
                                        'slug'  => "subitem.php",
                                        'title' => "subitem"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'   => "subitem.php",
                                        'title'  => "subitem"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'  => "subitem.php",
                                        'title' => "subitem"
                                     ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'  => "subitem.php",
                                        'title' => "subitem"
                                     ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'   => "subitem.php",
                                        'title'  => "subitem"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'  => "subitem.php",
                                        'title' => "subitem"
                                     ),
                                    array(
                                        'slug'   => "subitem.php",
                                        'title'  => "subitem"
                                    ),
            )
                ),                      
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem "
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"
            ),
            array(
                'slug'   => "navItem.php",
                'title'  => "navItem"            
            )
                );

    ?>
```

Comment: @C0dekid update my code with error line

Comment: Try changing `<?php foreach ($item as $subitem){ ?>` to `<?php foreach ($item['dropdown'] as $subitem){ ?>`. That should solve the problem. I will explain in an answer if it does.

Comment: Try `foreach ($item["dropdown"] as $subitem)`

Comment: @TobiasF. yes that worked.. Is a little messed but at least it display witout error.. So just have to clean up my code.. :)

Comment: @alexlaexalex i've added a more detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where the error occurs you are doing the following line of code:

```
<?php foreach ($item as $subitem){ ?>
```

`$item` contains 3 Elements with the keys `'title', 'slug' and 'dropdown'`. Now you try to iterate over `$item`:

```
//foreach
$item = ['title'=>'mytitle', 'slug'=>'myslugh', 'dropdown'=>array(...)];
```

On the first iteration you try the following:

```
$subitem = 'mytitle';
$title = $subitem['title'];
```

The problem is you iterate over the wrong array, you have to use `$foreach($item['dropdown'] as $subItem)` instead.